# Android bluetooth app to connect phone to smart speaker full-duplex?

Tags: android, bluetooth, sonos

I'm wondering if anyone knows of an app that will allow an android phone to connect to a smart speaker (like Sonos One) via bluetooth, and have the two devices function like an intercom with full-duplex (2-way) audio.  There is an app called [Intercom](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.androidintercom) on the Play Store, but it will only connect to another phone, not a smart speaker.  There are walkie-talkie apps, but these also connect two phones (and require push-to-talk).

Comment: Problem with Bluetooth is the very limited range; developers don't like working on a concept that's hobbled from the start. Would you accept a connection by WiFi? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=co.sonofy.smartroomsolutions&hl=en_US

Comment: In my case that would work. Thanks for the heads-up. I will check it out.

Comment: I did check it out, and the signal is one way on that app.  So the phone can "broadcast" to the speaker, but the speaker can't talk to the phone.

Comment: Another app for phone to phone is Walkietooth https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.masmil.walkietooth&hl=en_US&gl=US

Answer (score 1):

Only the Sonos Move has proper Bluetooth support, and only a few audio profiles. You need to use WiFi, and even then you have no access to the microphone on the Sonos.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the come-backs.  If anyone trying to solve this same problem runs across this thread, try searching Amazon for "full duplex wireless intercom." I found eMACROS Portable Wireless Intercom System on there.  Sound isn't as good as a Sonos or Echo, but it works.